# Protecting a cell from consecutive POSTs

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create a time-based/triggered lock on data in cells of a spreadsheet so that the data in the cell is not changed during certain periods of the day. But before I created the time-lock to remove the range protection I need to first lock the cell when the first POST is made to it.

How do I lock a cell from being edited after the first POST so that consecutive POSTs to the same cell during the lock period do not change the data?

Note: The app is executed as me and anyone including anonymous has access to it.

```js
doPost(e)
{
   ssNew = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId);
   var sheet = ssNew.getSheets()[0]; 
   var cell = sheet.getRange(1,1);
   var visits = cell.getValue();
   
   cell.setValue(e.parameter.name);
     SpreadsheetApp.flush();
     
  var lockrange = sheet.getRange(1,1);
     var protection = lockrange.protect().setDescription('Protected');
     var me = Session.getActiveUser();
     protection.removeEditor(me);  
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to store a flag in some kind of persistent memory: like using the [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) (probably script properties in this case) or a spreadsheet cell in another sheet. The doPost() could then check if that flag is set before changing it.

You could also look at [programmatically protecting the cell](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection) against edits by users.